# Removing unnecessary dates

Tags: r, as.date

I have a list of days in 2017 and I have to remove the date, which do not have to calculate

```
days_2016 <- seq(start_day, end_day, by="days")
holidays <- seq(start_h, end_h, by="days")

work_days <-
```

How to make list without holidays?

Comment: Perhaps `?setdiff` or `%in%`

Answer (score 0):

Like docendo said:

```
days_2016 <- seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by = "days")
holidays  <- seq(as.Date("2016-05-01"), as.Date("2016-06-30"), by = "days")
workdays <- days_2016[!days_2016 %in% holidays]
```